# Do Rotten Tomatoes scores often predict a movie's box office success (or lack thereof)?

Tags: box-office

I go watch movies in theater every 2 weeks, and when choosing what to see, I decide often based on Rotten Tomato critic score. This score is now shown by Siri after each time I ask which movies are playing, so I don't even have to visit the Rotten Tomatoes website.

My point is, I use that RT rating to decide what to see, and many others probably do too. I'm curious to know how much correlation there is between a movie's RT score and its box office performance.

Comment: Is there any correlation between box office performance and the movie actually being good?  I'd be more interested in the latter, since I know some of my favorite movies were box office flops.

Comment: @Andrew I agree, however I'm curious nevertheless.

Comment: *"I'm curious nevertheless."*  Sounds reasonable.  I'm curious about the answer to your question as well.  :)

Comment: Not in the biggest blockbuster sense. Just look at the scores of the Michael Bay films. Only one "fresh" but nearly every film earned a ton of money.

Comment: @Catija I recall Michael Bayer saying WTE *"So I make films for teenage boys, sue me!"*.  It made me wonder whether teenage boys a) are indeed prominent ticket buyers for his films, and.. b) tend to vote on films on Rotten Tomatoes (I'm thinking a lot of the votes would come from people in their 20s and 30s, but I could be very wrong about that).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I was referring to critic scores, anyway, so the demographic would likely be under-represented in critics groups.

Comment: I think it's all about the advertising. Most people go to watch a movie that's most advertised and other people are talking about at the moment.

Comment: suggestion: untick the answer because correlated implies dependent but uncorrelated doesn't imply independent? even if there's no straight line correlation doesn't mean there can't be some other dependence https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188242/for-intuition-what-are-some-real-life-examples-of-uncorrelated-but-dependent-ra

Answer (score 9):

Nope. Based on [this plot](http://www.quora.com/Can-Rotten-Tomatoes-ratings-predict-film-box-office-results-over-a-year) (by film statistics specialist [Stav J. Davis](http://www.quora.com/Stav-J-Davis)) of 81 films that grossed more than $20M in 2012, there's no straight-line correlation between the Rotten Tomatoes ***critics*** score (e.g. public reviews) and the amount that each film made at the box office:

[image]

There's also no *significant* correlation between the **user review** scores (although the chi value was fractionally higher if you exclude all films that grossed less than $100M

[image]

In short, how good a film rates on Rotten Tomatoes has little bearing on its box-office take.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the graphs for lower-grossing films. I would think that there would be more correlation between the two at that point.

Comment: @Catija - Based on a [similar study](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~aldous/157/Old_Projects/kennedy.pdf) in 2003, I'd say that the answer is not.  The major predictors of box office success are the level of marketing, the number of screens and the named actors.

Comment: It would be interesting to see a more up-to-date graph. The OP mentions that the score is shown by Siri, which I'm guessing is a recent development. This would signify that Rotten Tomatoes might be more influential now than it was in 2012

Comment: Is there a version of the top chart with a trend-line?  That would tell us, better, if there is a correlation.

Comment: well, correlated implies dependent but uncorrelated doesn't imply independent?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188242/for-intuition-what-are-some-real-life-examples-of-uncorrelated-but-dependent-ra